# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net MVC using scaffolding to create pages with dropdowns?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Over the years when I have created an ASP.Net MVC project and used scaffolding to create the controller and views or views from an existing controller I have always had to create any dropdowns by hand after the pages are created. I recently started a new project and for some reason when I used scaffolding to create the pages it knew enough to build the dropdowns automatically.

I have not been able to recreate this. Any idea why this worked and how to get it to work again?

Is the default scaffolding even capable of doing dropdowns?

Comment: You're using MVC 4?  Not 5?

Comment: Sorry ... ASP.Net MVC 5.2.2

Comment: My experience has been that if your classes have the appropriate foreign keys defined so that the model properly describes the relationships then the scaffolding will build the appropriate controls.